# jQuery - how to "activate" input when I move on it with pressing "tab" key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers

I have a form and when I move on an input that contains where the user is supposed to enter a date (after clicking into it, I fire datetime picker from jQuery-UI), nothing happen.

When I click into the field, the datatime picker is fired, that's fine. But when I move onto this input by pressing the `tab` key, the datetime picker is not activated. How do I activate it?

I tried

```
$(function() {
  $('body').on('blur','.date_field', function(e) {
    $(this).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'}).focus();
  }
});
```

But it doesn't work. I also tried to use `keypress` or `keydown` and comparing the key-codes, but it doesn't work neither.

How to activate the datetime by moving on an input by pressing the `tab` key?

**EDIT:**

I tried also `bind` with no success.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`js` at Question is missing closing `)` at event handler. Initialied `.datepicker()` before `blur` event. Added `tabindex="1"` to `input` element. Actually, `blur` event is not needed, and would appear to recursively add focus to `input` element.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".date_field").datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
  //$("body").on("blur",".date_field", function(e) {
  // $(this).focus();
  //})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
Date: <input type="text" class="date_field" tabindex="1">
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer. I have in the code the `$('body')` section because I am adding the `.date_field` dynamically.